# save and retrieve images from database by relative address in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, relative-path

i have a windows form that contains two tabs . first tab is for save image and second is for retrieve. 
Also my source pictures are in my bin project address like this :

> C:\Users\BlackRose\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RealState\RealState\bin\Debug\HomePics

now I wonder that how I can save address of pictures to sql server and retrieve them even I change my project location ...

I Already try these codes :

```
string path;    
public myForm()
{
    path = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\HomePics";
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
}
```

then write some sql and c# code in a function and save imagePath and imageName that no problem to save them.
but I'm sure I must configure path to set relative path, because the string of path that saved in db is like this :

```
C:\Users\BlackRose\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RealState\RealState\bin\Debug\HomePics\pic1.jpg
```

with this method, the problem occurs when I want to move my project folder to otherwhere
and all of addresses in db will be useless.

could you tell me any useful method so i can retrieve it in any conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HomePics` as folder name while saving the `Path` into Database as below:

```
path = "\\HomePics\\pic1.jpg";
```

while accessing Image Path from Database just Add Below Code:

```
String strRelativePath=getRelativePathfromDB();//gives you \Home\pic1.jpg
String strAbsoluteFilePath= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "")+strRelativePath;
```

So finally `strAbsoluteFilePath` contains below `Absolute` Path:

```
C:\Users\BlackRose\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RealState\RealState\bin\Debug\HomePics\pic1.jpg
```

the above path changes the dynamically depending on the `location` from where you are executing your project.

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: sorry i did not get you , are you asking to know the steps for inserting path into database?

Comment: great ,please let me know if you need anything more. have a nice Day :)

Comment: thanks alot ... it's work in any condition... thanks again :)

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you - Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

1. Save the relative path in the database, i.e. path relative to `\HomePics` (root folder) in your example (provided that all files are in that folder and its subfolders).
2. In the config file of your application, add a setting to say where the root folder is located, e.g. in your `<appSettings>` you could have an entry `<add key="ImagesRootFolder" value="C:\Images\HomePics" />`. Alternatively, you could save the same information in the database as well, in a table separate to images.